# Ajax lento al hacer consulta POST php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

estoy una mini red social con PHP. Ahora estoy implementando un sistema de likes el cual funciona con PHP y ajax, el sistema funciona pero al dar click en el botón de like se tarda 5-7 segundos en mostrar el contador de likes.

Existen 2 tablas, una donde van las publicaciones (posts) donde la columna *likes* guarda el contador; La otra tabla es likes donde verifico si el usuario ya ha dado like en x publicación.

PD: intenté reducir al máximo el codigo PHP

JS

```js
//.up es el botón de like
$('body').on('click', '.up', function () {
    var postid = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/like.php",
        data: {
            'post_id': postid
        }, success: function (likes) {
            //muestra la cantidad de likes
            $('.count-like#' + postid).text(likes);
        }
    })
});
```

PHP:

```php
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

     #ver si ya ha dado like
     $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `userid`, `postid` FROM likes WHERE userid = '$userid' AND postid = '$post_id'");
     $row = mysqli_num_rows($q);

     #extraer likes actuales

     if($row) {
        #si ya dio like anteriormente

       #imprimir contador
        echo $countLike;

     } else {
        #si no dio like 

        #imprimir contador
        echo $countLike;

     }   
}
```

Comment: Si lo que te interesa es devolver el contaje no hagas una consulta completa que luego debes recorrer en PHP, usa `SELECT count(*) FROM likes etc..` y así te ahorras algo... pero diria que el problema esta en el código que no vemos, pues a menos que un usuario tenga miles de likes no debería tardar tanto

Comment: Y hay una cosa que no entiendo demasiado de tu consulta... la pones así: `"SELECT userid, postid  FROM likes WHERE userid = '$userid' AND postid = '$post_id'"`  lo cual implica que su resultado van a ser los mismos datos que estas consultando repetidos tantas veces como aparezcan... creo que necesitas si o si usar el count(*) realmente, je, pues no sacas nuevos datos, solo una cantidad de lineas de respuestas de los mismos datos que ya sabes y estas consultando.

Comment: y para terminar, está muy bien que quieras reducir el código de la pregunta, pero debe ser coherente... no se ve que es **$countLike** ni porque lo pones en un condicional que da exactamente la misma respuesta hagas lo que hagas (al menos en la pregunta)